# Odoo report error: Qweb error maximum recursion depth exceeded

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo, odoo-8, qweb

I'm trying to create a  report and everything seemed fine with my code except I got this error while printing the report

Here's a part from error message:

```
  File "/opt/odoo8/odoo/addons/report/models/report.py", line 135, in translate_doc
    return self.translate_doc(cr, uid, doc_id, model, lang_field, template, values, context=context)
  File "/opt/odoo8/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 268, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo8/odoo/addons/report/models/report.py", line 106, in translate_doc
    doc = self.pool[model].browse(cr, uid, doc_id, context=ctx)
  File "/opt/odoo8/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 268, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo8/odoo/openerp/models.py", line 5266, in browse
    return self._browse(Environment(cr, uid, context or {}), ids)
QWebException: """"""""""""""""""""""""""""""maximum recursion depth exceeded" while evaluating
"translate_doc(doc_id, doc_model, 'user_id.partner_id.lang', 'school_erp.report_printstandard')"" while evaluating
"translate_doc(doc_id, doc_model, 'user_id.partner_id.lang', 'school_erp.report_printstandard')"" while evaluating
"translate_doc(doc_id, doc_model, 'user_id.partner_id.lang', 'school_erp.report_printstandard')"" while evaluating
```

and here's my code :

in report.xml:

```
<template id="report_printstandard">    
            <t t-call="report.html_container">
                <t t-foreach="doc_ids" t-as="doc_id">
                    <t t-raw="translate_doc(doc_id, doc_model, 'user_id.partner_id.lang', 'school_erp.report_printstandard')"/>
                </t>
            </t>
        </template>
```

and here's my module:

```
class school_standard(osv.osv):
    _name = 'school.standard'
    _rec_name = "code"  
    _columns = {
        'name':fields.char('Standard Name', size=256, required=True),
        'code':fields.char('Standard Code', size=8, required=True),
        'user_id':fields.many2one('res.users', 'User'),     
        'student_line':fields.one2many('school.student', 'standard_id', 'Students'),
    }   
    def get_uid(self, cr, uid, context=None):
        return uid
    _defaults = {
        'user_id': get_uid,
    }
school_standard()
```

What is wrong in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the same id `<template id="report_printstandard">` from `'school_erp.report_printstandard'`.
You shoud create a new template with different id:

```
<template id="report_printstandard_document">
    <t t-call="report.external_layout">
        <div class="page">
            <!-- Your Code-->
        </div>
    </t>
</template>

<template id="report_printstandard">    
    <t t-call="report.html_container">
        <t t-foreach="doc_ids" t-as="doc_id">
            <t t-raw="translate_doc(doc_id, doc_model, 'user_id.partner_id.lang', 'school_erp.report_printstandard_document')"/>
        </t>
    </t>
</template>
```

Comment: @youta I'm glad I could help

Answer (score 1):

You are facing the issue which is the Qweb error maximum recursion depth exceeded because of you are passing the wrong args on **translate_doc** method
and you are trying to passing the same id which are having the template on translation mechanism not to used the template of qweb report.

**translate_doc() works some things like :**

Helper used when a report should be translated into a specific lang

```
<t t-foreach="doc_ids" t-as="doc_id">
    <t t-raw="translate_doc(doc_id, doc_model, 'user_id.partner_id.lang', account.report_invoice_school_erp.report_printstandard_documentdocument')"/>
 </t>
```

**Parameters of translate doc function :**

**1. param doc_id:** id of the record to translate

**2. param model:** model of the record to translate

**3. param lang_field':** field of the record containing the lang

**4. param template:** name of the template to translate into the lang_field

I hope my answer may helpful for you :)